# Data and transaction within WCF vs Web-api platform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I have worked with both technologies yet I’m about to build a new backbone services layer and thinking about WCF vs Web-Api.

The idea is to create a layer of services that will be consumed by both internal .NET components and  by front applications.

The following are issues are not relevant to this case:

- TCP, UDP
- Proxy generator
- WS-* standards like Reliable Messaging, Transactions

I'm considering about 2 approaches:

- Web-api for app front application above n-tier WCF services
- Web-api for app front and for a flexible services layer, thus avoiding HTTP hop between services

Our system is financial oriented, some services will operate as data services using the using some kind of OData and some will perform complex financial transaction (using complex types).

I've read about the new stuff that was recently added to Web-Api 2 and it seems to be a leading platform. I've Googled a lot about pros and cons and that WCF is still alive (or frozen).

A few of the relevant references:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341414/WCF-or-ASP-NET-Web-APIs-My-two-cents-on-the-subjec

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172.aspx

Under the assumption that all the services are on the same LAN and this is targeted to enterprise system, **what would you recommend and why?**

Answer (score 3):

Here's the question... Do you need transport layer flexibility or are you fine with them being http(s) only services? If the services are HTTP-only and (as you say) you don't care about proxy gen and WS-* then I can't for the life of me think of a reason why you'd use WCF.

The programming model for REST / plain old http(s) is just so much leaner, the MVC "style" much more natural and not to mention that WCF can just get really complex really fast, makes me think that I would need a really good reason to choose WCF in 2013...

Not to throw a spanner into the works, but have you considered Service Stack:

https://servicestack.net/download

That's what I'd be using... (btw I'm not affiliated with them in any way / shape / form).

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple endpoints/transport protocols, or the ability for other applications to consume your services in .NET and work with them as you would any other referenced library (via web reference and a SOAP endpoint) the WCF should be your choice.

If you're looking for something lightweight and convention-based and/or you're looking to create a RESTful API, and HTTP(S) is an adequate transport, then Web API is the way to go. In this case, if you want the strong typing that you'd get with a SOAP web reference you'd probably be wise to write a reusable library that acts as middleware for consuming the services and providing data.